# Custom UITableView - iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I used a `UITableView` and I built a `customCell`, the `UITableView` is connected to `NavigationController`.

I want that cell 1-3 use the `navigationBar` (e.g. click on cell pass to the next view)
and cell 4-5 just remain as clickable cells (e.g. I click on this cell and the cell background changes).

In the storyBoard the identifier is equal to `Cell`.
Right now any action pass me to the other view, can some one help?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain your problem in detail, the expected outcome, and the required outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, be sure to to add your custom cell as:

```
YourCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

If you don't need the custom cell, then just leave it as `UITableViewCell`.

Use the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath` method for the action:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString *segueIdentifier = [[NSString alloc]init];
     switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            segueIdentifier = @"segue1";
            break;
        case 1:
            segueIdentifier = @"segue2";
            break;
        case 2:
            segueIdentifier = @"segue3";
            break;

     if (indexPath.row != 3 && indexPath.row !=4) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method for this.

Implement this method in your tableviewcontroller and in this method do following stuff.

If you have added tableview in viewcontroller then do following -

1) In .h file add delegates `@interface TestTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

2) In .m file in `(void)viewDidLoad()` method add

`self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.dataSource=self;`

If user click on 1-3 cells call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_SHOWDETAILS sender:self];`in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to redirect to new page

and for 4-5 cells change cell background color in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.